# Control being shifted to next line in a class

Tags: python

```
class car():
    def __init__(self,name,model,colour,pricerange,state):
        self.name = name
        self.model = model
        self.colour = colour
        self.pricerange = pricerange
        self.state = state

    def fthree(self):
        print("Name: "+self.name)
        print("Model: " + str(self.model))
        print("Colour: " + self.colour)
```

**Output**:

```
Name: tiago

Model: 2016

Colour: white
```

I am not using `'\n'`. But the control is being shifted to the next line in the output. Does this always happen when working with a class in Python?

Comment: Try it without a class and see that it's unrelated.

Comment: Please indicate, using a tag, whether you are using Python 2 or 3. I'm assuming Python 3, due to the `print` function call.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with `c = Car('a','b','c',10,'ca'); c.fthree()` - I don't get blank lines.

Comment: The code you show us doesn't, by itself, have this problem. Perhaps you are calling it with an incorrect value with a trailing newline in the first place. You should [edit] your question into a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function (in Python 3) defaults to printing a newline character:

> ```
> print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
> ```
>
> Print `objects` to the text stream file, separated by `sep` and followed by `end`.

If you don't want this behavior, pass an empty string for `end`:

```
print("hello ", end="")
print("world")
```